# How to reduce the number of words before a command in Linux Ubuntu terminal?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, terminal

I am running Ubuntu Linux on my machine. I use terminal **a lot**. Before writing any command the full path is displayed like so:

```
iamfaiz@iamfaiz-HP-250-G1-Notebook-PC:/media/iamfaiz/Faiz/Code/sandbox$
```

*I hate it* because only half of the terminal screen is left for me to write commands. How can I change it? Is there any configuration file for it or something? I want to convert this:

```
iamfaiz@iamfaiz-HP-250-G1-Notebook-PC:/media/iamfaiz/Faiz/Code/sandbox$
```

TO

```
sandbox $
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set your PS1 to display only the relative path of the current working directory in your ~/.bashrc or /etc/profile:

```
export PS1='\W \$ '
```

Answer (score 2):

It is depending upon your shell, you want to configure its *prompt* often thru the `PS1` (or `PROMPT` perhaps) environment variable.

I do like [zsh](http://zsh.org/) and use it as my login & interactive shell (change yours using `chsh`) and have

```
PROMPT="%m %2~ %T %# "
```

but YMMV.

Your solution might be:

1. find out what is your shell, perhaps with `ps $$` or `grep $(id -nu) /etc/passwd`; it might be GNU [bash](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/).
2. read the documentation of your shell ([this one](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/index.html) is for `bash`)
3. find out how to configure its prompt (e.g. in `~/.bashrc` if using [bash](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/)).

Alternatively, change your shell (using [chsh(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/chsh.1.html)...) to another one `zsh` or perhaps [fish](http://fishshell.com/) and also go thru the above steps.

You might be delighted to [STFW](http://onlineslangdictionary.com/meaning-definition-of/stfw) to understand what [RTFM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RTFM) means. If using a lot the terminal, do `sudo aptitude install manpages manpages-dev` then type `man man`

You could end your shell prompt with a newline.

You might realize that showing some part of your current directory in your prompt is practically very useful (e.g. when running `rm -rf *`).

You might want to learn more about auto-completion and configure wisely the completion of your interactive shell. It is a matter of taste also.

Answer (score 1):

In your `~/.bashrc` file set the `PS1` variable to the string that you would like to be the prompt, then log in again. This is mine:

```
PS1='$ '
```

That causes my terminal to look like this:

```
$ ls
foo bar
$
```

Answer (score 0):

Just to add to the others that if you want you make your prompt look even cooler (colors and what not) you can just use a .bashrc generator for a more visual way of seeing how things will look like.

There are tons of them out there, but this is the one that I used for mine.

http://bashrcgenerator.com/